# creating a data grid in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I want to know if there is an API to create a datagrid like here:

http://socghop.appspot.com/gsoc/program/accepted_orgs/google/gsoc2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From these:

http://roberto.open-lab.com/2010/01/18/javascript-grid-editor-i-want-to-be-excel/

I choose http://www.datatables.net/. It is extreme flexible, up to date and has a good documentation, well tested.

jqGrid is not free.
And Flexigrid is two years old and comes with jQuery 1.2.x.

Comment: +1 to datatables. An amazing community and an API that is easy enough for beginners too!

Answer (score 1):

There are several:

- [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)
- [Flexigrid](http://www.flexigrid.info/)
- [YUI Data Table](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/)

As well as many others...

My personal favorite is jqGrid, which is extremely flexible and can do pretty much everything you need. On the other hand the API can be a bit overwhelming when you are first getting started. You also might be interested in [jqGrid-PHP](http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx) which is integrated with your server-side PHP code - but it is not free.

Comment: +1 for jqGRid. I have used it an a large-scale inventory application. Once you get to know it's API it just do everything.